# Adding dependency in Android Studio fails

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

It's my first time adding a custom library in Android Studio and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to use this library. https://github.com/lewisjdeane/L-Dialogs And it's instructions are simple enough. Drop the .aar file in the libs folder and add this to the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs:RENAMED_FILE_NAME_HERE@aar'
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

but I keep on getting "Error:Failed to find: uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs:ldialogs:"

Here's a picture of my project structure and what not [image: Project Setup]

And here's my build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oxpheen.notes"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs:ldialogs@aar'
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

If you could help me out with this it would mean a lot, thank you!

Comment: can u run gradle from CLI interface with --info switch .. then inspect the detailed log for the issue.  what AS version ?

Comment: Like I said, really new to gradle and dependencies, just switched from Eclipse, so I don't really know what you are saying @RobertRowntree

Comment: in eclipse, did 'project.properties' contain the library? if yes then just do an import to AS and it should build ok.

Comment: I'm not using eclipse. I meant I was using eclipse before ever using android studio. I started this project in android studio though. How do I import it? The github page just said copy and paste the aar file into the libs folder  @RobertRowntree

Comment: Can you post your actual build.gradle?

Comment: I updated my post with the build.gradle file code @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with latest Android Studio (v0.8.11), and ran into the same issue. Tried different combinations, and finally got it working.

saved the file as `ldialogs.aar` under `libs` folder, inside the "app" module (not under project root folder)

Add the below to build.gradle of your "app" module folder (not your project root build.gradle).

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs:ldialogs@aar'
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

I was also able to verify under `File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> Dependencies`

To double check, i created a hello world dummy project with AS v0.8.11, copied that ldialogs.aar file to the `libs` folder under `app` dir, and just copy-pasted above lines. Verified i was able to import the ldialogs package in `MyActivity.java`...see the red box highlight (tried importing a fake package to show difference):

[image: gralde aar]

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. I updated the post with my build.gradle file, without the ldialog dependencies.

Comment: try removing the `compile` line but keep `flatDir`, click `sync now`; And then add back the `compile` line. I also made another silly mistake initially i saved the filename wiht first char "I", not "L", but fixed it.

Comment: what is your AS version

Comment: Tried all that as well and it's 0.8.9

Comment: i have it working with v0.8.11, may be consider updating your AS and try. My gradle changes also [reflect in AS module dependencies](http://i.imgur.com/MfjsiRW.png) , check my update to answer.

Comment: I checked my project structure and it looked just like yours, even updated to the 0.8.11 canary version and still getting the same thing. Originally did you just copy the aar file into the libs folder? Or is there a way to better import it or something. I'm just not getting why it's not identifying it.

Comment: @FernandoRamirez  please check my update to answer. Try creating a new dummy hello world project, and copy paste those gradle lines. Open [my image link in a new browser window](http://i.imgur.com/c1MjeFw.png) to see more clearly. I hope it helps,